# How to retrieve a value from an element with selenium and python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I am a beginner in programming. I use `python3` and `selenium` to get values from two elements of a website.

I want to retrieve the current and total page number, see picture below.

[image]

In my example the current page number is 43 and the total 510.

When I inspect the elements in question I get the following source code:

[image]

The first line indicates the current page field, while the second indicates the total page number.

I managed to retrieve the xpaths of both elements, which are

for the current page element:

```
'//*[@id="openSDPagerInputContainer2"]/label[2]'
```

for the total page element:

```
'//*[@id="openSDPagerInputContainer2"]/input'
```

Things like:

```
totalPages = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('afterInput').get_attribute('innerHTML').split()[1]
currentPage = sys.argv[2]
```

or:

```
totalPages = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="openSDPagerInputContainer2"]/label[2]')
currentPage = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="openSDPagerInputContainer2"]/input')
```

do not function. For the first code snippet, I get a `selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: afterInput` error message and for the second an `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'` error message and without the `.split()` I would receive erroneous outputs.

How to I manage to retrieve the current and total page number with `selenium` and `python3`?

Comment: Use `.` to select element by class `.afterInput` using CSS selector. Also, use `find_element_by_xpath()` (notice *element* without 's') if you are to find only one element

Comment: Hi, har07, thank you for point out to me my spelling mistake.